# Jquery check for class, if class is present, check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run a simple function using Jquery. This is the pseudo code for the function-

"On page load, check for the class name "active."
 If a class like that exists, check the corresponding checkbox.
 Otherwise carry on." Pretty straight forward.

The HTML for the code we're targeting :

```
<li class="inactive" aria-selected="false">
        <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkLink" value="Accessories">
            Accessories 1
    </li><!--box example won't be marked "checked" on page load-->



 <li class="active" aria-selected="false">
            <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkLink" value="Accessories">
                Accessories 2
</li><!--box example will be marked "checked" on page load-->
```

The Jquery I wrote to create the interaction:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("RUNNIN");

        if ("li").hasClass("active"){
             $('.checkBox').prop('checked', true);
        };

    alert("CODE RAN");
});
```

The alerts are there to test where in the code it all breaks. They aren't even loading at all currently, at the start or end. They do run, however, if I delete the conditional statement entirely.

Checking in the google dev tools it detects a syntax error on my "if" line. Screenshot added here:
[Follow link here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JTAV.png)

Guess I can't embed images yet. The error line says this in the console 
"Unexpected token . on line 17" which is the if("li").hasClass line.

So it isn't expecting . but I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax there. Deleting it leads to it not expecting the { and so on so forth until the whole line is deleted.

I'm having a hard time finding the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wrong: `if <condition> { <code to execute> }`, right: `if ( <condition> ) { <code to execute> }` -> [MDN: if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Instead of alerting, you might want to study `console.log()`  if you dont know it yet.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Getting these answers helps my mastery of the syntax as well as general good programming practice, and gives me rules that I can follow as I keep coding. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below to check for all `li` elements having class `active`, then find checkbox elements with class `checkBox` then check it.

```
$("li.active").find('.checkBox').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Beautiful code. Fixed my issue and did everything you said, I'll mark this answered when the countdown ends on it.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: It's super clean. I think the other responses on here show my approach could potentially do the same thing, once I fix my syntax error, but getting everything to run correctly using one small line of code is just really nice. Hoping I can get to this level of mastery someday.

Comment: Also, I noticed `hasClass` doesn't look for exact class. If I use `hasClass` to look for `active` class, it gets both `li` elements as `inactive` contains `active`. So, it is always best to use `selectors`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("RUNNIN");
  $("li.active").find('.checkBox').prop('checked', true);


  alert("CODE RAN");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="inactive" aria-selected="false">
  <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkLink" value="Accessories"> Accessories 1</li>
<!--box example won't be marked "checked" on page load-->
<li class="active" aria-selected="false">
  <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="checkLink" value="Accessories"> Accessories 2
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, is it considered good practice to do this when I present a question?

Answer (score -1):

Code Run Before Vote

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("RUNNIN");

        if ($("li").hasClass("active")){
             $('.checkBox').prop('checked', true);
             //alert("asas");
        }

    alert("CODE RAN");
});
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".active > input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

totally agree with @Martijn but ...

You are forgetting a ( and a ) and a $

```
// You have this:
if ("li").hasClass("active"){
// which should be
if( $("li").hasClass("active") ){
  ^ ^------------------------ ^
```

Also, you can do this a lot easier:

```
$('.checkBox').prop('checked', $("li").hasClass("active"));
```